# Adding images to slick from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to add images to my slick slider from jQuery. The default structure should look like this according to slick.

```
<div class="your-class">
  <div><img src=""> </></div>
  <div><img src=""> </></div>
  <div><img src=""> </></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that I need to set my images from jQuery, but when I do, the images don't get structured by slick and are just left inside the "your-class" `div`.

This is how I am trying to accomplish this right now. The problem with this is that slick is supposed to create child elements and append this content to and structure it.

```
let image = ['<div><img class="selectedImage" src="',
             e.target.result,
             '" title="',
             escape(theFile.name), '"/></div>'].join('');

$(".your-class").append(image);
```

This is the result of this:

```
<div class="your-class slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div class="slick-list draggable"></div>
  <div><img src="link_to_image"> </></div
</div>
```

This is the wanted result:

```
<div class="your-class slick-initialized slick-slider">
  <div class="slick-list draggable">
    <div class="slick-track">
      <div class="slick-slide">
        <div>
          <div><img src="link_to_image"> </></div
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about a slider that has already been initialized before, and you now want to add new slides to it? Then do it properly, using the `slickAdd` method provided for exactly this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let image = ['<div><img class="selectedImage" src="', e.target.result,
  '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/></div>'
].join('');


$(".your-class").append(image);

$('.your-class').slick('unslick')

//initialize again here .your-class
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with initialize again here .your-class ?

Comment: I worked on slick plugin couple of month ago and I ended with this solution, you are appending data in 'your-class' and slick is not aware from your appended data that is why you need to unslick first and then initialize again

Comment: and by initializing again you mean to call this again after $('.your-class').slick({ dots: true }); ??  Because i tried that without any success

Comment: No i don't get any errors but the slick is acting as if there is nothing inside the "your-class" div. So im guessing its not appending any elements to the "your-class" element..??

Comment: Not it worked, i had to append the image again after unslick and then initialize the slick again!